# Is group of units of a polynomial ring only constant polynomial which is involved in R

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let R be a integral domain(or maybe field)

edit : Let R be a field. The group of units of R[x] is $$ a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + a_{n-2} x^{n-2} + \cdots+ a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 $$(or infinity) such that $$ a_0 ∈ R^* $$

Some say, the unit group of R[x] is the unit group of R.

What I'm confused is that the second sentence seems to show its unit is constant polynomial only which is involved in unit group of R and first one is all the polynomial but the constant is unit group of R.

Which one is correct and what I missed the point?

Thanks.

Comment: The second sentence (= first claim) does not make sense. Please rewrite it.

Comment: Do you really mean R[[x]], i.e. the ring of formal power series? Or is this a typo? Why do you tag this "field theory"?

Comment: It's the other sentence that needs rewriting, "the group of units is a polynomial..." does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is true:

$$R^\times=(R[X])^\times$$

Proof:

Let $a\in R^\times\subseteq R$. Then the inverse of $a\in R$ is just the inverse of $a$ in $R[X]$.

Conversely if $f\in (R[X])^\times$ with the inverse $f^{-1}$ then

$$0=deg(1)=deg(f\cdot f^{-1})=deg(f)+deg(f^{-1})\tag{1}$$

Hence $deg(f)=deg(f^{-1})=0$. Thus $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are invertible elements of $R$

Note: The third equality holds if and only if $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Does it mean that a group of unit of R[X] is just constant polynomial?

Comment: Yes. Thats right.